# upload video using AFNetworking without Block UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking

I need to upload image without showing user some progress indicator. So basically like when you upload image in twitter/instagram when you do the submit, the upload view disappear instantly and you back to main ui.
Currently I'm using AFNetworking to upload the content and it success. Been searching for the solutions but can't find anywhere.

This is my current code for uploading the image to my server.

```
- (void)sendImage {

HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
HUD.dimBackground = NO;
[HUD setLabelText:@"Uploading"];

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kBaseURL,@"api/v1/media"];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uploadImage, 1);
NSString *base64PhotoString = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"caption": textfield.text,
                             @"photo_data":base64PhotoString};

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

[manager POST:url
   parameters:parameters
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
          [weakSelf successBlockFrDictionary:responseObject];
      } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          [HUD hide:YES];
          [weakSelf showErrorMessageForError:error];
      }];
}
```

Comment: remove the HUD ... or i am getting your question wrong

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use a weak self in the block since your self does not hold manager object.

Comment: Please elaborate, what exactly you want to implement?

Comment: @cjd This is what i wanted: Let say user click button to go UploadViewController, in this controller user select image and submit  OKButton. But after he click ok button the UploadViewController is dismiss and user present with the main view controller. While the image is still uploading in background. Hope it explains.

Comment: Ok means you want to implement background upload right?

Comment: Implement your webservice code in any singleton class or whereever you want except the UploadViewController and call it from there.